# IIS forms authentication cross domain not redirecting to correct domain

Tags: iis, cross-domain, forms-authentication

I have 2 sites running on one instance of IIS 7.

`A.site.com`
`B.site.com`

These sites use forms authentication and there is one form for logging in on site A.

So if i try to access a restricted page on site B with URL

`B.site.com/TEST/`

i get redirected to

`A.site.com/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2TEST%2f`

I can then enter username and password to authenticate. So far so good.

After authentication I get redirected to

`A.site.com/TEST/`

instead of

`B.site.com/TEST/`.

Can anyone tell me how i can get around this problem and make IIS redirect me to the correct page?

Note: the authentication works fine - i can go to the page `B.site.com/TEST/` and i am no longer redirected to the login page. So the problem is just redirecting to the wrong site or the value of `ReturnUrl` should not be a relative path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround might be to force the user to go back to the last page using JS instead. Not a great answer though i admit. I think this is an IIS bug since the documentation to set up forms authentication with different sub-domains does not mention this problem at all.

EDIT:

A better answer is change the loginUrl to include the domain.

```
loginUrl="https://A.site.com/Login.aspx?domain=B.site.com"
```

Then handle the redirect client side

Comment: This worked so i am selecting it as the correct answer however i don't like it. I am really getting sick of IIS. Why do they bother giving a functionality which doesn't work?!